# Pandas giving a keyerror to an element that exists

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset that consists of 2 columns, time and 1 day active users for a google service. I set the time column as index and parsed it with pd.to_datetime. When I try to index an element in the time column, it gives a keyerror. I have pandas, datetime,dateutil.parser imported. I am new to python so I am stumped on what it could be.

Here what the dataset looks like:

```
                            1day_active_users
                     time   
2015-03-23 00:00:00-04:00             19687.0
2015-03-24 00:00:00-04:00             19437.0
```

Code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_path)
data.set_index('time', inplace=True)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data.loc['2015']
```

Error message: KeyError: '2015'

Comment: `df.loc['2015']` runs fine, `df.loc['2018']` returns error. Are you sure you have data in 2018?

Comment: `df.loc['2018':]` would give data from 2018 on.

Comment: Yeah, the dataset goes from 2015-2019. I changed it to 2015 and I still receive the same error

Comment: what does `df.index.dtype` output?

Comment: You may have different timezone offset in your `time` index.

Comment: I should try to set a timezone in the dataframe?

Comment: Hey sorry for a long response, internet has been down. df.index.dtype outputs as dtype('O')